# version control for wordpress? (wordpress folder and database at same time)

Tags: database, backup, git, version-control, wp-filesystem

I am familiar with version control to some extent. I have been using git and github for school purposes.

Now when I use wordpress it makes sense that I can use git when developing on my local machine.

- Can i Use git on my server also? I am using bluehost shared hosting.
- Can we store versions of database also at those instants when we do commits in git?

I doubt this will work. But I believe other developers must have similar problems How did you solved this problem?

I am looking for a solution where you can save both files and database at same instant.

I tried to do some research of my own also and this is was the solution that looked promising : VersionPress
*but this is still in development hence not ready yet.

Comment: I am not aware of a one-click, git-like way to sync database and file structure but as written there is nothing about this question that strikes me as WordPress specific, making it off-topic.

Comment: I personally export the database tables to a file, `.zip` 'em and make a folder in my project like `__db__` and store the file within it, and then `add` and `commit` on local, and `push` to server.